# Is there any solution such that..

Tags: number-theory

Is there any positive integer solutions of $x$, $y$, $z$ such that both $$\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{x+y+z}$$ and $$\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{xyz}$$ are integers?

**Edit**: Forgot to mention that $x$, $y$, $z$ are distinct positive integers.

Comment: Where did you get this from? (Also x = y = z = 1.)

Comment: I can find two solutions right away: $(1,1,1)$,$(3,3,3)$.

Comment: darn I forgot to write x, y, z are distinct positive integers

Comment: What I wonder is the speed at which people down vote when they can surely understand that they can write something besides trivial solutions. 
Does this look like a homework question? It is just that I am curious about these set of equations and I can't find any non-trivial solution to it so would love to know analytical take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A remark, how to start: The second condition can be written as Diophantine equation 
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2=nxyz,
$$
and it is easy to see that we must have $n=1$ or $n=3$. This is already very helpful. Compare also with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568860/integer-solutions-of-the-equation-x2y2z2-2xyz).

For $n=3$ the triples $(x,y,z)$ with $\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{xyz}=3$ are known as [Markov numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_number), and we can produce a Markov tree. Now it gets easier if we also require that $(x,y,z)$ is a solution of the Diophantine equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=m(x+y+z)$.

Comment: reference I like http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hurwitz_A_1907.pdf

Comment: Thanks Dietrich, it is really helpful and pushed me to the right direction. I will try to see if along the Markov Tree is there any solution possible for  Diophantine equation $$x^2+y^2+z^2=m(x+y+z)$$
Also thanks for the Reference Will Jagy.

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, definitely! Also, I like it to read in German....

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the closest we can get. Tried first million members of markov chain without any success.

Answer (score -1):

**Special case**

Well, if $x = y = z$ then your equations become

$$\frac{3x^2}{3x} = x$$

$$\frac{3x^2}{x^3} = \frac{3}{x}$$

If they are coupled, then you notice that $x = 1$ is the simplest result. There is also $x = 3$: $3/x$ is an integer if and only if $x = 1$ or $x = 3$.

Unless you count negative integers too, in that case you have also $x = y = z = -1$ and $x = y = z = -3$