# Find the positive integral values $n$ can take :${(x+y+z)}^2=nxyz$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

> Find the  positive integral values $n$  can take for which  :${(x+y+z)}^2=nxyz$ is solvable for positive integers.

**My try:** Due to symmetry WLOG let
$x\ge y\ge z$.

Now ,making it in a quadratic in $x+y$,we have
$$nxyz={(x+y)}^2+2(x+y)z+z^2$$ or $z| {(x+y)}^2$. But I don't know what to do with this. Also I tried playing with inequalities to get $$nyz\le 9x$$ and the equality condition $x=y=z$, yields
$$nx=9$$ or $n$ can take the values $(1,3,9)$ but I can't find more.

I know this question has been asked before but I have not learned that much.

I also tried using a little bit of calculus but nothing promising came  up.

Comment: @RobertZ   the solutions are too complex and i have not learned about pells equation yet.

Comment: @Robert, there is a recent answer at the same question by https://math.stackexchange.com/users/54563/calvin-lin   which uses only contest-level techniques, and considers just finding the appropriate coefficients $n$

Comment: @RobertZ  Calvin:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930438/equation-with-vieta-jumping-xyz2-nxyz/3599276#3599276

Comment: Quantum, Calvin Lin put an answer at that question using methods appropriate for you  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930438/equation-with-vieta-jumping-xyz2-nxyz/3599276#3599276

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks for pointing out!